# Can't use BitScanForward64

Tags: c++, visual-c++, intrinsics, visual-c++-2012

I'm building a chess engine in c++ that uses bitboards (__int64s) and I need to use BitScanForward64 in order for some calculations. But when I call it, I get this error:

> error C3861: '_BitScanForward64': identifier not found

I include it like this:

```
#include <intrin.h>
#pragma intrinsic(_BitScanForward64)
```

It's the same with BitScanForward64.

I use *Visual Studio 11* on *Windows 7 (64 bit)*.
CPU: *Intel Core i7-2600K*

I haven't done many projects with c++ before so I 
don't know why this is happening. Please help!

Comment: are you compiling for **x64**? the BSF64 & BSR64 intrinsics are **only** available for x64 targets.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BitScanForward64 issue in Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626891/bitscanforward64-issue-in-visual-studio-11-developer-preview)

Answer (score 6):

_BitScanForward64 is only available in x64 builds.  If you're targeting Win32, the only available intrinsic is _BitScanForward.

Comment: Thank you, now I can call the function. :) Although, it didn't work as I thought. I give a function the value 2^x, and it's going to return x. I need to use a fast bitscan function in order to increase the engine speed.